# Intermittent audio / sound output after installing ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: windows, linux, audio, ubuntu-12.04

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS as a second OS (Windows 7 being the original one).

I haven't tested it extensively, but so far, it seems to work fine... more or less.

When I plug my headphones to my laptop I keep hearing this intermittent sound that comes on and off every second, aprox. It's like the sound you hear when you start using an audio app (Rythmbox, YouTube video, etc.) after being doing something unrelated with audio for a while (editing text or whatever); it's like an "audio output ready" sound, but you normally hear it only once when you start listening to music, for example.

What's strange is that when I listen to music in Rythmbox or I watch a video on YouTube, the sound is ok, it's normal, but if I stop using an audio app and leave my headphones on, then the intermittent sound begins.

Has any of you experienced something like this? If so, how did you fix it?

Thanks.

Regards.

Comment: I just found out that that's a Chrome problem. When I have Chrome open I get that sound, but not when I'm using Firefox. I guess I'll have to use Firefox in Ubuntu, unless any of you guys know how to fix that.

Comment: I solved a similar problem following [this answer at AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/a/177228/53503).